# How to rigorously prove from set theory that piecewise functions exist?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have two functions $f$ and $g$ from the set $S$ into the set $T$. Suppose further that we have subsets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of $S$ which are disjoint and whose union is $S$. How does one rigorously prove, from ZFC set theory, that there is a unique function $h$ which agrees with $f$ on $S_1$ and agrees with $g$ on $S_2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existence: $h$ is the set $(f \cap (S_1 \times T)) \cup (g \cap (S_2 \times T))$.
Uniqueness: if $h_1,h_2$ are two such functions, then $h_1 \cap (S_i \times T)=h_2 \cap (S_i \times T)$ for $i=1,2$ so $h_1=h_1 \cap (S \times T)=h_2 \cap (S \times T)=h_2$.